# What is the output of expression c = a>2+b!=6?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, evaluation

Recently I came across this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 10, b = 20, c;
    c = a > 2 + b != 6;
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

What is the logic behind the output being `1`?

Comment: [Operator precedence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Comment: A good exercise is to manually add the proper parentheses that reflect the order of operations so you can see it for yourself.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your title says "C" language but your tags have C++ language.  Which language are you programming in?  C and C++ are distinct languages.  Please edit your tags appropriately.

Comment: C or C++ both would give the same result @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the [precedence of the operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

`+` has higher precedence than `>` and  `>` has higher precedence than `!=`.

```
a > 2 + b != 6
```

is evaluated as:

```
((a > (2 + b)) != 6)
```

or more specific:

```
((10 > (2 + 20)) != 6)
```

where `(10 > (20 + 2))` is evaluated to `0`, because `10` isn't greater than `22`.

So the expression is unfolded to:

```
(0 != 6)
```

which evaluates to `1` because `0` is not equal to `6` -> `(0 != 6) == 1`.